# Error when deploying Spring app to Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

I tried deploying this sample [Rest + Spring sample application](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/) to my Cloud Foundry account through Eclipse STS and Cloud Foundry plugin, however I get this error:

> HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative :
>   /customer/print of full path:
>   http://restdemo-api-v1.cloudfoundry.com/customer/print

However if I run locally in my local Tomcat 7 server, I get the response.

Any ideas why I experience this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would suggest you run your applications locally on CloudFoudndry micro, which is identical in most respects to CloudFoundry cloud
- While uploding the app to cloud from command line, add "-t" argument to push, so you will get a detailed information of error.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that Cloud Foundry uses Tomcat 6 as its Servlet Container. I would recommend you to check your application locally on a Tomcat 6 instance rather than a Tomcat 7.